# Replace parentheses in pyspark with replace_regex

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, expr

```
+---+------------+
|  A|           B|
+---+------------+
| x1|        [s1]|
| x2|   [s2 (A2)]|
| x3|   [s3 (A3)]|
| x4|   [s4 (A4)]|
| x5|   [s5 (A5)]|
| x6|   [s6 (A6)]|
+---+------------+
```

The desired result:

```
+---+------------+-------+
|A  |B           |value  |
+---+------------+-------+
|x1 |[s1]        |[s1]   |
|x2 |[s2 (A2)]   |[s2]   |
|x3 |[s3 (A3)]   |[s3]   |
|x4 |[s4 (A4)]   |[s4]   |
|x5 |[s5 (A5)]   |[s5]   |
|x6 |[s6 (A6)]   |[s6]   |
+---+------------+-------+
```

When I applied each of the codes below, the parentheses and the whitespace before them were not replaced:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df.withColumn("C",
               expr('''transform(B, x-> regexp_replace(x, ' \\(A.\\)', ''))''')).show(truncate=False)
```

or

```
df.withColumn("C",
               expr('''transform(B, x-> regexp_replace(x, ' \(A.\)', ''))''')).show(truncate=False)
```

The obtained result:

```
+---+------------+------------+
|A  |B           |value       |
+---+------------+------------+
|x1 |[s1]        |[s1]        |
|x2 |[s2 (A2)]   |[s2 ()]     |
|x3 |[s3 (A3)]   |[s3 ()]     |
|x4 |[s4 (A4)]   |[s4 ()]     |
|x5 |[s5 (A5)]   |[s5 ()]     |
|x6 |[s6 (A6)]   |[s6 ()]     |
+---+------------+------------+
```

Comment: When giving an example it is almost always helpful to show the *desired result* before moving on to other parts of the question. Here you refer to "replace parentheses" without saying what the replacement is. Your code suggests it is empty strings. In other words, you wish to remove parentheses. (I could be wrong.) Moreover, you haven't said whether you want the formatting of other lines adjusted accordingly. All that would be mute if you merely showed the desired result (before "When I applied...").

Comment: is `df.withColumn("C", F.regexp_replace('B', '[\\(\\)]', ''))` what you are looking for?

Comment: @ werner, That is applied on columns with String values, but I want it for array values. Thanks

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, thank you for your comment, I edited the question and showed the desired result

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to apply `regexp_replace` to each element of the arrays individually. Am I right?

Comment: @werner, Exactly. I added an example of the expected result

Comment: try `df.withColumn("value", F.expr("""transform(B,x-> regexp_replace(x,"\ (.*\)",''))"""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **split** the array value and get only the **`first index`** from the array.

- (or) using **`regexp_replace`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+---------+
#|  A|        B|
#+---+---------+
#| x1|     [s1]|
#| x2|[s2 (A2)]|
#+---+---------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- A: string (nullable = true)
# |-- B: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

df.withColumn("C",expr('''transform(B,x -> split(x,"\\\s+")[0])''')).show()

#using regexp_replace function
df.withColumn("C",expr('''transform(B,x -> regexp_replace(x,"(\\\s+.*)",""))''')).show()
df.withColumn("C",expr('''transform(B,x -> regexp_replace(x,"(\\\s+\\\((?i)A.+\\\))",""))''')).show()
#+---+---------+----+
#|  A|        B|   C|
#+---+---------+----+
#| x1|     [s1]|[s1]|
#| x2|[s2 (A2)]|[s2]|
#+---+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UDF that removes all elements from the array that match the regular expression `r"\(.*\)"`. If necessary, you can change the regexp to match `r"\(A.\)"` if that is required.

```python
import re
replaced = F.udf(lambda arr: [s for s in arr if not re.compile(r"\(.*\)").match(s)], \
                 T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
df.withColumn("value", replaced("B")).show()
```